# Solution to nonlinear integro-differential equation

Tags: matlab, ode

This question is regarding MATLAB implementation of the solution to IDE.

Consider IDE:

[image]
where the K(r',r,\theta) is the Kernel of the integration. Is there a simple implementation of the solution to this kind of equations? I know how to solve it in general, but I'm wondering if you could suggest something simpler and well implemented in MATLAB.

Comment: I don't know about simpler, but the [Chebfun](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/) package [might be able to do it numerically](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun/examples/integro/html/WikiIntegroDiff.shtml). Also [see this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95224).

Comment: @horchler: Thanks! I "googled Chebfun" already and trying to apply to my problem.